# Can pkg_resources find a resource located under the dist-info dir created when extrtacting a whl?

Tags: python, python-3.5, setuptools, distutils, python-wheel

My setup is dependant on packages downloaded as whl's and extracted and their resources thus reside in the ".dist-info" dir as specified in

I am failing in finding those files using pkg_resources.resource_filename

Here's a zsh + ipython output that demonstrates it:

```
➜  jupyter-adapter git:(develop) ✗ find eggs/jupyterhub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.ovo/ -name 'error.html'
eggs/jupyterhub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.ovo//jupyterhub-0.8.1.dist-info/data/share/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html
➜  jupyter-adapter git:(develop) ✗ bin/ipython
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 15 2017, 17:45:49)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: [x for x in sys.path if 'jupyterhub' in x]
Out[2]: ['/Users/oded/work/jupyter-adapter/eggs/jupyterhub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.ovo']

In [3]: import pkg_resources

In [6]: pkg_resources.resource_filename('jupyterhub', 'jupyter/hub/templates/error.html')
Out[6]: '/Users/oded/work/jupyter-adapter/eggs/jupyterhub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.ovo/jupyterhub/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html'

In [7]: open(_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-724e07d998de> in <module>()
----> 1 open(_)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/oded/work/jupyter-adapter/eggs/jupyterhub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.ovo/jupyterhub/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html'
```

Setup 2 (virtual env):

```
(jupyter-adapter) root@public-notebook (Ubuntu 14.04) ➜  jupyter-adapter find /root/jupyter-adapter/share/ | grep 'error.html'                                                                                                               17-12-27 08:40
/root/jupyter-adapter/share/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html
(jupyter-adapter) root@public-notebook (Ubuntu 14.04) ➜  jupyter-adapter ipython                                                                                                                                                             17-12-27 08:41
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2016, 00:00:00)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pkg_resources

In [2]: pkg_resources.resource_filename('jupyterhub', 'jupyter/hub/templates/error.html')
Out[2]: '/root/jupyter-adapter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html'

In [3]: open(_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-724e07d998de> in <module>()
----> 1 open(_)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/jupyter-adapter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html'
```

What am I missging?

Comment: How do you install `jupyterhub`? If I install it via `pip install jupyterhub`, `pkg_resources.resource_filename('jupyterhub', 'jupyter/hub/templates/error.html')` returns a valid path as expected. Even if I cheat and build a source distribution of `jupyterhub` myself, and pass it as a dependency to the setup script, the resource is still found.

Comment: In setup (2), the more standard one, within a virtual, indeed with pip3. Where does you setup place the html with respect to the virtual env root, if I may ask?

Comment: If I have installed `jupyterhub` via `pip install jupyterhub`: `$ echo $(pip show -f jupyterhub | grep Location | sed 's/Location: //')/$(pip show -f jupyterhub | grep error.html)` prints `/Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ ../../../share/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html`. So it's the `share` directory in the venv root that contains static files for the package.

Comment: If I build the a source tar `jupyterhub-0.8.2.dev0` from latest sources and pass it as a dependency for my package `spam` and run `python setup.py install` for `spam` to force non-pip install of `jupyterhub`, then I get the path in egg root: `pip show -f jupyterhub | grep Location | sed 's/Location: //' | xargs -I {} find {} -name error.html` yields 
`/Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub-0.8.2.dev0-py3.6.egg/share/jupyter/hub/templates/error.html`.

Comment: it's the share directory in the venv root that contains static files for the package for me as well. My only problem which I understand does not occur for you is that I can't locate it via pkg_resources